# Is it possible to omit some annotation attributes but not all?

Tags: java, annotations

In java tutorials - Annotations part, question 3 (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/QandE/questions.html), an annotation are expected to be used as below:

`@Meal("breakfast", mainDish="cereal")`

I tried to define the annotation as below but it does not allow the above usage.

```
public @interface Meal {
    String value();
    String mainDish();
}
```

Is it possible to omit the first attribute name as the question suggested?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the shortcut only works if you specify the `value` attribute and nothing else.

Otherwise you must explicitly write `value=`, that is the correct version would be `@Meal(value = "breakfast", mainDish = "cereal")`

Comment: Thanks, that confirmed my speculation that the question may not considered that aspect.